# How can I launch Chrome as a background process from the command line?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, google-chrome-extensions, google-hangouts

I have two profiles in Chrome. One for **Home** and one for **Work**.

When you add the [Hangouts Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd/related?hl=en) to a profile, it uses the email of that Chrome profile rather than letting you sign in. So in order to use Hangouts with my work email, I need to use the **Work** profile. I'd like to keep using **Home** as my default profile, but that means I need to first launch the **Work** profile (triggering the Hangouts extension to start) and then close the window (it'll remain in the background and taskbar).

The following command will open my work profile:

`open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Profile 1"`

... but I'm wondering if there's another flag that'll open it as a background process too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `--no-startup-window` does the trick, but if you then try to launch Chrome normally, it'll open the most recent profile (in my case Work). I saved myself some trouble by just running Hangouts off Chrome Canary rather than profile switching.